# Create a silent mp3 from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, mp3, lame

I am trying to create a silent / empty mp3 file of (x) seconds using the command line. Quite a simple task I thought!

It seems [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php) is able to do something like this, but I am unable to find anything that leads to achieving this.

Has anyone been able to do something like this?

Comment: In an ideal world I would be able to do this directly with ffmpeg and not need to use another library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is a unix-oriented approach (although sox is cross-platform and should get it done on windows only as well).

- You'll need [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) - "the [cross-platform] Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs".
- This wrapper perl script, helps you generate any seconds of silence: http://www.boutell.com/scripts/silence.html

  ```
  $ perl silence.pl 3 silence.wav
  ```

`silence.pl` is quite short, so I include it here, since it's public domains:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$seconds = $ARGV[0];
$file = $ARGV[1];
if ((!$seconds) || ($file eq "")) {
        die "Usage: silence seconds newfilename.wav\n";
}

open(OUT, ">/tmp/$$.dat");
print OUT "; SampleRate 8000\n";
$samples = $seconds * 8000;
for ($i = 0; ($i < $samples); $i++) {
        print OUT $i / 8000, "\t0\n";
}
close(OUT);

# Note: I threw away some arguments, which appear in the original
# script, and which did not worked (on OS X at least)
system("sox /tmp/$$.dat -c 2 -r 44100 -e signed-integer $file");
unlink("/tmp/$$.dat");
```

Then just `lame` it:

```
$ lame silence.wav silence.mp3
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution SoX looks interesting but more than probably what I am looking for. I managed to get a silence using http://sourceforge.net/projects/wavi-avi2wav/. This has a pre built silence.exe which will be easier to drop into use.

Comment: Very nice, the script can even take decimal value as input. For my requirement I needed a very short (nearly empty) wav: silence.pl 0.1 silence.wav

Comment: The other answer is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 76):

You can use this command.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=mono -t <seconds> -q:a 9 -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3
```

Change `<seconds>` to a number indicating the number of seconds of silence you require (for example, `60` will create a minute).

Comment: do you know how to specify the bitrate of the output file?

Comment: nvm, simply remove `-q:a 9` and add `-b:a 192k` or whatever bitrate you want

Comment: Works great. Especially lovely is the ability to install ffmpeg command-line tools without previously installing the whole mass of development and deployment tools (Xcode + Home-brew and all related junk).

Comment: @DavidSchumann to have a constant bit rate (CBR) works `-b:a 64k` (bit rate >= 64000), but  `-b:a 32k` not works (it create a VBR). I don't get it, what I'm missing?

Comment: For some reason this results in a very large MP3. With the compression mp3 uses, I would expect 10 minutes of silence to be quite small, but it's 3.3MB. One minute is 236K.

Comment: If you want to have a file that's shorter than 1 second, for instance 100 ms, "-t .1" does not work but "-t 0.1" does work.

Comment: `ffmpeg -ar 48000 -t <duration> -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -acodec libmp3lame -aq 4 <filename>` is significantly faster for me

Answer (score 6):

`sox -n -r 44100 -c 2 silence.wav trim 0.0 3.0`  - this will create a 3sec stereo silence file.
Here **n** for null file handler, **r** is the sample rate and **c** is the number of channels.

Then just lame it:

`$ lame silence.wav silence.mp3`

Answer (score 4):

Avoid the nuisance of creating a wav header, and let lame handle a raw file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=? | lame -r - - > silence.mp3
```

setting ?=2 gives a 11 second file (@ standard 44KhZ, etc... parameters).

Note: this was tested on Unix; I understand there are dd and lame for windows, too.

Comment: dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=100 | lame -s 8 -r --bitwidth 8 --signed -b 8 - a.mp3

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set volume to zero on existing file

```
ffmpeg -i existing_music_file.wav -t 4 -filter:a "volume=0.0001" silent.wav
```