# How can I control background music with button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried two version

The first one autoplay is working on Google Chrome but how can I control with button that I can play or pause the audio?

```
 <embed name="pop" src="pop.mp3" loop="true" hidden="true" autostart="true">
```

The second one autoplay is not working on Google Chrome but I can control it with button in IE or FireFox

```
<audio id="myAudio">
<source src="pop.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

The buttons

```
<button onclick="playAud()" type="button">Play</button>
<button onclick="pauseAud()" type="button">Pause</button>
```

And the Javascript

```
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAud() { 
aud.play(); } 

function pauseAud() { 
aud.pause(); }
```

So how can I deal with this problem?

I want the Audio autoplay in background
And then I can use button to play or pause it

Comment: worked in chrome 70 http://jsfiddle.net/L6u94pkx/

Comment: @Mohammad I want to autoplay the audio and then i control it with button

Comment: Alos work http://jsfiddle.net/L6u94pkx/1/

Comment: Since GC61, it's been an end-user option: chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Audio autoplay not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/audio-autoplay-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: @freedomn-m I have tried this one , it is not suitable for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to trigger the play function on init:

```js
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function play() {
  aud.play();
}

function pause() {
  aud.pause();
}

aud.play(); // this will do the trick :)
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
<source src="https://wiki.selfhtml.org/local/Europahymne.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<button onclick="play()" type="button">Play</button>
<button onclick="pause()" type="button">Pause</button>
```

---

**Old solution:**

You could remove/add your embed-element like i did here. This might be hacky, but it could be a solution for you.

```js
var audiowrapper = document.getElementById('audio-wrapper');
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

function play() {
  if (!audiowrapper.hasChildNodes()) audiowrapper.appendChild(audio);
}

function pause() {
  if (audiowrapper.hasChildNodes()) {
    while (audiowrapper.firstChild) {
      audiowrapper.removeChild(audiowrapper.firstChild);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#audio-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: -300px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="audio-wrapper">
  <embed id="audio" name="pop" src="https://wiki.selfhtml.org/local/Europahymne.mp3" loop="true" hidden="true" autostart="true">
</div>
<button onclick="play();" type="button">Play</button>
<button onclick="pause();" type="button">Pause</button>
```

Comment: When I press the play, it jumps a player above the button

Comment: you could hide the "audio-wrapper" using "display: none;". I've edited my answer. Please take a look at it.

Comment: or take a look at the new solution in my answer. it might be the better one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<audio id="sound" src="sound.mp3" autoplay="0" autostart="0"></audio>
<button onclick="playAud()" type="button">Play</button>
<button onclick="pauseAud()" type="button">Pause</button>

<script>
    let aud = document.getElementById("sound");

    function playAud() { 
        aud.play(); 
    } 

    function pauseAud() { 
        aud.pause(); 
    }
```

Comment: I made it so it doesn't autoplay, it's only supposed to play when you click the button.

Comment: I tried.It is not I want. But thank you for your help