# No Sound of A-Frame on Chrome desktop Browser

Tags: google-chrome, audio, aframe

My Windows Chrome Browser (71.0.3578.98) is not playing any sound from A-Frame. Code:

It also does not play sound from other A-Frame sites (eg. http://ngokevin.github.io/a-wakens/). Firefox works fine.

Thank you for clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn’t have audio autoplay since April 2018. It requires user gesture. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490453/717508