# Why does html audio played by a web host only play when submit button is pressed

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I was writing an html code with the following code:

```
<audio src="/home/user/public_html/copyrighted-music.mp3" hidden autoplay><embed src="/home/user/public_html/copyrighted-music.mp3" width="180" height="90" hidden="true"></audio>
```

I used an `<embed>` for those people without `<audio>` supported browsers but with or without the embed tag, the audio only plays when the submit button of my random form is pressed although I was expecting audio to play after it has loaded and not after a press of a button.
Just some more background information:

1. the /home/user/public_html/ is the path of my file I am using with my web host
2. my web host is x10 hosting
3. I tried different arrangements of audio and embed arguments and the same result is present
4. I also have a back to top button which somehow stops the audio from playing after the submit button is pressed
5. I notice the link changes once each of the two buttons is pressed so maybe the audio likes a certain link?
6. I have a javascript controlled welcoming pop-up that also comes in action once loaded

So again, how do I make audio play once loaded and not after a press of a submit button?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Chrome makes autoplay audio near impossible [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) and despair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome) But beware two most upvoted answers are relying on bugs (which seem to have been fixed already)

Comment: The problem still is there on my friend's mobile safari, and I am using a web host not the default chrome html runner. Also, the audio actually plays on my chrome, just not automatically, it is with the help of a submit button.

Comment: it isn't duplicate but it help fix my problem with my web host running in chrome, I am not sure about my friend's safari problem though...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to learn some JavaScript to improve your code.
The HTML5 has a tag named `input` ,you need to use it and write some ECMAScript to use together.
This is my web code about the music,I think this can be a example to you.

```
<input type="bottom" value="music" onclick="music()">
<script>

function music() {
    var change_music = document.body.createElement("audio");
    change_music.autoplay = 1;
    change_music.controls = 1;
    change_music.src = "/home/user/public_html/copyrighted-music.mp3";
    document.body.append(music);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: umm... all it gives is a text input and the `onclick` function doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
<src="/home/user/public_html/copyrighted-music.mp3" hidden autoplay>
<embed src="/home/user/public_html/copyrighted-music.mp3" width="180" height="90" hidden="true">
</audio>
```

Comment: I prefer no controls
and is there such thing as a `<src>` tag?
also, I know how remove control argument to remove controls

Answer (score -1):

```
<audio controls>
 <source src="/home/user/public_html/copyrighted-music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Yous should probaly read more on audio in html5 espcially from w3schools site. By the way why on earth are using `copyrighted-music.mp3`?

Comment: it was a name replacement I am using for this question in case someone thinks I took credit