# Onload audio worked but now doesn't

Tags: javascript, audio, onload, behavior

So I have a very simple code which worked **yesterday**. I get back on the computer this morning and it looks like it does not work anymore.

What I checked:

- Whether or not my function runs `onload` (it does)
- If the path for the audio file is correct (it is)
- I tried putting the `src` directly in the `audio` tag (and deleting the `onload` call just to make sure). It still does not work.

The code:

#### HTML:

```html
<body onload="startMusic()">
    <audio id="audio" autoplay loop>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>

<!--rest of the page-->
```

#### JS:

```
const audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function startMusic(){
    audio.src = "./audio/myFile.mp3";
}
```

I don't have any console error.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try interacting with your page, for instance add `onclick = startMusic` in your JS and click anywhere.

Comment: Found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)