# How can I apply a JavaScript function on embedded audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

On my website I have an embedded audio that automatically starts and runs in the background (I have the audio embedded, because a normal  can't be autoplayed in chrome). Now I am trying to find a way to make that audio start at a random point in the clip.

```
<body onload="audiofunction()">
        <embed id="audio" src="berlin.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" autostart="true" loop="true">

        <script>
            function audiofunction(){
                var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
                alert(audio);
                var max = audio.duration + 1;
                audio.currentTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

That is how my Code looks like. I know that it works on normal audio, but with the embedded audio nothing happens.

Maybe you could help me.

Comment: In a specific version of Chrome? Both your example and with the `audio` tag works in my version of Chrome. Maybe the problem is somewhere else? Try create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: But does it also choose a random position in the clip, when you try it?

Comment: I did try but it does not work because the `embed` element does not have a `currentTime` property nor a `duration` one.

Comment: Okay i did not know that. I guess I have to find a way to make the normal audio work. Thank you

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx6pf13g/) and let me know if it works for you. As you mentioned though, this may not work for every user. For more information, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490453/11755228) from a different question.

Comment: Where is mp3 located? Same site as the page or on a site that you can't edit? It's impossible for the latter but might be possible for the former

Comment: The mp3 is my own, so it is located on the same site.