# play sound when page has loaded in Ionic4

Tags: html, ionic4

Not sure if it's related to Ionic, but when the page is loaded I have a button that play a sound.

If I click on that button - the sound does play.

Then, I wanted to play the same sound from that button - but when the page is loaded, so when the page is loaded - sound will play, when you click on that button - same sound will play.

```
NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
```

I tried using `ionViewDidEnter`, `setTimeout` for 5 seconds ... but I'm keep getting this error msg of permission ...

## UPDATE - MEI score

On purpose I set my permissions for `Auto play sound: Block` for finding the right solution.

I can raise the MEI score according to the following statement:

> On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been
>   crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.

This means:
- if somewhere on previous pages - I made a sound - switching to any other page - will also trigger sounds.
- Or a valid click ( that loads a silent sound just to "collect" the permissions ) - also does the trick ..

Counting on that - when loading the Ionic project for the first time, then `home.page.ts` is being loaded, the trick here, is, when I click on the menu item for selecting an inner page to go to -> this is considered a **valid** `click` event for allowing playing audio files - in which the sound which didn't work before ( because I kept refreshing the same page w/o any clicks ) - now works on page switch..

### UPDATE for background music ( for video games )

Found this thread ... I think it's the only way
[How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Comment: Even I'm getting the same error, the cause maybe media engagement score of chrome browser. `navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, (success) => console.log(success), error => {console.warn(error.toString());});`

Comment: If your issue is related to MEI score and if you find any guide showing how to improve to improve MEI score, please post here also @Ricky

Comment: so `navigator.getUserMedia` gives me `TypeError: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function`, so I used `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(` - response: `Promise { <state>: "rejected" }` .. then I clicked on that button that made sound - and retried that code - response is still "rejected" ... (?!)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is more related to browser permissions on automatically playing sounds.

> Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>   User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>   On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
>   The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.

You can find more information here:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio

The article goes on to suggest that when initiating programmatic audio play, a promise will be returned which can be used to handle success/fail cases, e.g.

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
  });
}
```

Comment: I thought so too, but loading that code - says that `audio`: request microphone permissions, `video`:  request camera permissions ( which makes sense ) - but both I don't need ... I just want to play audio ...