# JavaScript audio autoplay why not working on new version chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I can not play audio on autoplay in the new version chrome br!
Help me guys

```
const myAudio = new Audio('transient.mp3');
    myAudio.loop = true;
    myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);
    myAudio.play();
```

Comment: try Solution #2:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Because the user will need to have interacted with the domain before music can play. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes