# How to add an MP3 file as a background on a HTML page

Tags: html

I'm trying to add in some music to a landing page on my website, the file is called "LandingPageMusic.mp3" and it is in a separate folder called "Music". When I insert the following code into the body of the page, no music plays - I am using Google Chrome FYI.

```
<embed src="LandingPageMusic.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use HTML5, you can use `<audio>` now:

```
<audio autoplay loop style="display:none;">
  <source src="LandingPageMusic.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

This should give you an audio player that autoplays, and `style` will hide the player.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I want the music to automatically play and for there to be no player. How would I do this?

Comment: @Harry I've updated my answer with the `autoplay` attribute, `loop` attribute, and a `style="display:none;` attribute to hide the player.

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
<audio autostart loop>
      <source src = "LandingPageMusic.mp3">
</audio>
```