# Is there any way to autoplay video with audio in chrome in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i'm working on spa where i have to show banner video on top of the website. when loading video at initial phase is there any way to unmute the audio of video.

I have tried to unmute video and override but it's not working on chrome browser. i have read article about chrome autoplay video blocking but still is there anyway to unmute video.

tried below code

```
<video autoplay preload="auto" muted onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" oncanplay="this.play()" id="video-player">
<source src="https://###########" type="video/mp4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</video>

let audioPlayer = <HTMLVideoElement> document.getElementById('video-player');
audioPlayer.addEventListener('play', () => {
  // audioPlayer.muted = true;
  audioPlayer.play();
  audioPlayer.muted = false;
});

audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  this.showPlayBtn = true;
})
```

i need to auto play video with audio in all browser.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you setInterval and call it as soon as the video gets over.

Comment: Chromium automatically disables audio playback unless it was initiated by an user action or you've previously played a video on the same site, there are a few workarounds such as playing a small empty audio file first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Comment: problem is at initial loading video is not playing in chrome browser

Comment: @Checkium no at initial loading chrome is blocking autoplay video but when you use muted its working fine. But i want to play video and audio at the same time

Comment: @Rohit exactly, chrome blocks autoplay audio by default like I explained, read the question I linked

Comment: @Checkium thanks for the help... i have solve my problem by using muted in video tag and added audio button for unmute video

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular, you could use this external library [Videogular](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2). It's very easy to use and you could configure almost everything related to the video player.

Here you can see a live example of the use of this library [live-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-videogular?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

All you have to do to "autoplay" the video is to put the parameter "autoplay" to *true* as you can see below:

```
<video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" autoplay="true" controls>
```

You can try this in the [live-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-videogular?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts) adding this parameter.

Comment: i had tried but still getting same problem autoplay is not working in chrome

Comment: `<video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="video-player" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="https://############" type="video/mp4" crossorigin="anonymous">
            
        </video>`

Comment: according to the chrome policy at the initial loading of video, only auto play will work not both( audio and video at the same time ). i have created the audio button if user want to listen audio of that video then only audio will play. It solve my problem.