# Background Music in Javascript Won't Work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a small horror game and I can't seem to figure out how to add background music in javascript.

I looked up how to add it and I found a solution on w3schools, but when I tried it out, it didn't work. I'm trying to play the sound called backgroundMusic which is set to an mp3 file called bgmusic.mp3

```
var jumpscare;
var backgroundMusic;

music();

function music() {
jumpscare = new sound("jumpscare.mp3");
backgroundMusic = new sound("bgmusic.mp3");
backgroundMusic.play();
}
```

What I'm hoping to happen is for the music to start playing when I open the application.

Comment: Do you have Firefox's auto play disabler disabled?

Comment: Can you share link to w3 schools site so we can compare what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome autoplay has been disabled. A user will need to interact with the page first.

Answer (score 2):

`sound` isn't a valid constructor, did you mean [`Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) ?

As far as I know, you need to integrate a html `<audio>` tag to be able to play a sound.

According to W3School docs:

```
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

And on the `script` part :

```
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
x.play()
x.pause()
```

EDIT, this should work too :

```
const audioObj = new Audio(url);
audioObj.play();
```

A complete list of methods is avalaible here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods