# How to make autoplay audio work on chrome

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm creating a game and I need to add background music to it. I tried adding an audio tag in HTML and and adding autoplay and loop to it. It loops, but the audio won't play when I load the page.

I've tried using iframe, which I've found in many solutions, but none of them worked.

```
<audio autoplay loop controls>
<source src="bgmusic.mp3">
</audio>
```

I'm hoping that when I open the page, the music starts automatically, but instead, it stays paused.

Comment: You have to add the `muted` attribute, and frankly; if that doesn't work anymore; they've removed that functionality, you'll have to look into using JS/JQuery manipulation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)