# HTML5 audio autoplay not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, html

I have html5 audio like this in my page

```
<audio src="assets/media/bgaudio.mp3" id="audio" autoplay type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Here is jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#audio").get(0).play();
});
```

But getting an error when refresh the page.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://goo.gl /xX8pDD

Any idea to fix the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Comment: Yes because google chrome did not allow any media to autoplay until the user interact with it.

Comment: @HarsimranjitSingh how can fix the issue? is it impossible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome this may help you. try it It is an acceptable answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the *preload* attribute to make it work on chrome.
Also keep in mind that a user must interact with the domain for unmuted autoplay to work.

```html
<audio controls autoplay preload>
  <source src="assets/media/bgaudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">  
</audio>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Just do that

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="assets/media/bgaudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">  
</audio>
```