# Audio file starts only if url ends with /index.html

Tags: html, url, audio, routes

I inserted an audio file on my page, but it starts only if you apply /index.html at the end of the url. It does not work with my published url like https://musictest1.netlify.app/ but if I type https://musictest1.netlify.app//index.html audio file starts.

Environment: (Chrome)

Thanks for help

Comment: could u provide me password to access

Comment: It would be better if you provide us a password so we can check the site too.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To solve your issue it's important to place scripts/codes/images. Because without context it's very difficult to help you solve this problem.

Comment: Here the link: https://musictest1.netlify.app/

Comment: There you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome