# How to play audio/sound in firebase-messaging-sw.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm having an issue on how to play notification sound/audio file in `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. However the message was sent successfully. Here's what I've implemented so far

```
importScripts("https://gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.3/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.3/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: "...",
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  const options= {
    body: notification.body,
    icon: notification.icon,
    sound: "/media/notification.mp3",
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, options);
});
```

From what i've read from multiple source, firebase cloud messaging is only providing sound notification in mobile devices.

However i want to play audio/sound when the notification is showing up in my desktop/browser. is there a way to play the audio in the browser?

i've also tried to play audio like this

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  const options = {
    body: notification.body,
    icon: notification.icon,
    sound: "/media/notification.mp3",
  };

  const audio = new Audio("/media/notification.mp3");
  audio.play();

  return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, options);
});
```

but still the audio notification still won't play.

and here's is request POST to FCM `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`, with body params

```
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "Title Notification",
    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon": "/media/logos/png-Icon-Logo.ico",
    "sound": "/media/notification.mp3"
  },
  "to": "...", // firebase messaging token
  "priority": "high"
}
```

The notification is working with no problem, but there are no audio feedback when the notification shows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are encountering the problem of playing audio without user interaction. More info in this thread.

[Is it possible to play audio without the user interact with the web before? how would I do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62051711/is-it-possible-to-play-audio-without-the-user-interact-with-the-web-before-how)

The short answer is you can't right now

The long answer is you could do that by doing some tricks.