# How can I autoplay audio using lit-html?

Tags: javascript, lit-html

I'm currently making a game and I want to include a background music. I added this to the body

```js
<audio autoplay loop>
    <source src="assets/Tree_of_Life" type="audio/wav" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
```

But when I run lit-html, it won't play. I tried making it a template

```
const BackgroundMusic = (src) => {
  return html` <audio autoplay loop>
    <source src="${src}" type="audio/wav" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>`;
};
```

But again it doesn't work, how would I be able to autoplay this music with lit html?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few possible fixes :

1. Add the .wav extension at the end of your filename
2. Try in another browser and see if it's a browser problem. If it is, there are a few other ways to do that using an iframe for example : [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51630171/11187832)
3. Remove the autoplay loop attributes and launch the sound with javascript

Comment: it is a wav extension but ill try the others, thank you for your help