# Autoplay tag not working on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, audio, iframe, autoplay

So I have a music which only plays automatically on edge chromium. On firefox and chrome, it doesn't work. Any solution? THANKS

```
<audio id="music" autoplay loop style="display:none">
<source src="Music1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src="Msic1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Can this help? "How to make audio autoplay on chrome" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome

Comment: Concerning the second solution, can you please explain me what to do? Where he says: "Solution #2:
There is also another workaround for this according to @Leonard"

Comment: Because I don't understand if I should put the audio in the iframe. Or the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

[visit this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)
i think you should use **iframe** and audio tag as well for non-chrome browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me. Just need to add the *preload* attribute.
Keep in mind the user must interact with the domain, so click something in any page of the site, once he interacts everything should work fine.

```html
<audio id="music" autoplay loop preload>
<source src="Music1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src="Msic1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```