# HTML, Javascript game, I would like to find a way to play sound on page display

Tags: javascript, html, audio

In other words I would like to go around the Chrome settings that prevents sounds from playing on page load (not just on my computer but for every future user).
Here is the interesting part of my index:
`<body onload="playCreditMusic()">`

And the javascript function:

```
const playCreditMusic = () => {
  const audio = new Audio('../sound/sound.mp3');
  audio.play();
};
```

Here is the error message:
`DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Comment: Actually I saved this link earlier to check it out later today, but I will le you know if it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olivier. Actually there's another way of accomplishing this task. Here's how i did it:

**HTML**

```
<figure>
        <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
        <audio
            controls autoplay loop
            src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3">
                Your browser does not support the
                <code>audio</code> element.
        </audio>
    </figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    margin: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Note that i didn't use the `onload` event or any inline javascript. This is because according to the [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp#inline_code_is_considered_harmful) this makes websites vulnerable to attacks such as code injection and many others. I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately the ```autoplay``` doesn't seem to work. But It's a good start, thanks!

Comment: Humm.. This is odd. Here's where you can find more about the `audio` tag in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#:~:text=The%20HTML%20element%20is,streamed%20media%2C%20using%20a%20MediaStream%20.)

Comment: Thanks I will look into it, but I think chrome blocks the autoplay option.
There might be a solution in here though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome#:~:text=The%20default%20HTML5%20audio%20autoplay,getElementById('myAudio').