# HTML - Play mp3 in background (chrome / opera)

Tags: google-chrome, background, mp3, opera

I've been trying to get an MP3 playing automatically in the background of my website for some time now, which doesn't work in Chrome and Opera because of their autoplay policies from 2018.

Now I've been looking for solutions for example here:
[How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)
and either it didn't work or only in one of 3 browsers.

Is there an updated bug or a way to play an MP3 automatically without the user having to press play manually in chrome and opera or are all these workarounds already patched?

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way to get around the autoplay policies for audio.

Now, the user action doesn't necessarily have to be the user pressing a play button.  It could be a click on anything.  So, maybe your application has an introduction screen where they click a button to go into it, and music starts playing then.