# HTML/JS - Play audio file on page load

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I would play an audio file (on loop) after I open my website.

I know browsers have restrictions about autoplay, but is it possible to autoplay any audio using JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Comment: @KarthikRadhakrishnan I already tried this, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't any guaranteed way; MDN has the [following general guidance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide):

> As a general rule, you can assume that media will be allowed to autoplay only if at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The audio is muted or its volume is set to 0
> - The user has interacted with the site (by clicking, tapping, pressing keys, etc.)
> - If the site has been whitelisted; this may happen either automatically if the browser determines that the user engages with media frequently, or manually through preferences or other user interface features
> - If the autoplay feature policy is used to grant autoplay support to an  and its document.
>   Otherwise, the playback will likely be blocked. The exact situations that result in blocking, and the specifics of how sites become whitelisted vary from browser to browser, but the above are good guidelines to go by.

Current policies of Chrome and Safari are that you can not just play audio once the page has loaded (unless it's muted).

Chrome has the [following policies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes):

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
- User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
- On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
- The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.
- Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Safari has the [following guidance](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/) regarding autoplay:

- Websites should assume any use of  or  requires a user gesture click to play.
- It’s important to detect if auto-play was denied, since users now have the ability to turn off all forms of auto-play, including silent videos.
- Auto-play restrictions are granted on a per-element basis.

Comment: Yes, I already see these rules, are there any ways to increase the volume of the audio (from 0) without breaking any rules?

Comment: Afaik there are none. From what I understand, changing volume will have the browser reevaluate these rules.