# Why is autoplay not working everytime i resfresh my website html5 audio

Tags: html, audio

I have this code to autoplay an audio but everytime I refresh the website it stop playing. I'm using PHP ,Xampp based website sorry I'm new at this.

```
<audio controls autoplay><source src="kuizzeraudiobg.mp3" type="audio/mp3" loop="true" autostart="true"></audio>
```

Comment: According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50490304/231316), auto play might be disabled by default in most browsers, something I personally agree with.

Comment: how do I enable auto play or is it not possible?

Comment: is there an alternate way to enable autoplay?

Comment: I would read the [Chrome blog post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/) on this. FF and Safari probably have similar policies. This is a moving target, probably, so don’t be surprised if it changes in the near future, too.

Comment: Also, your question doesn’t have anything to do with PHP or a database, please don’t tag it as such. The tags should focus solely on the question, not ancillary things that the rest of your application might do.

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay is blocked by default on modern web browsers. [here is the official MDN web doc guide for autoplay restrictions in browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)