# Why is the HTML <audio> element not autoplaying in any browser?

Tags: html, audio, autoplay

I am working on an interactive story for a school project. I am trying to make music to go with my various endings.

I used this the first couple times and it worked once or twice on Chrome then stopped working.

```html
<audio class="ending-tunes" src="../../../../../Audio/Stonebank - Life & Death.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" autoplay></audio>
```

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51630171), tried the two first solutions and neither of them worked which is expected given I later found a comment saying that it no longer works but it was worth a shot and I didn't see that comment until after I tried it.
I had also tried this simple script:

```js
var audio = Document.getElementsByClassName("ending-tunes");
audio.play();
```

but it didn't work either.

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490453) which told me that Google has some policies on autoplay. With that information in mind, I decided to go over to Edge and run it there, thinking that Edge would work. It didn't. My project is due tomorrow so if you see this and can answer, please do so right away. I thank you kindly!

Comment: Your users need to interact with the page before it's able to produce any sound.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, that's what I learned from the second answer I referenced.  That just means that the user has to click anywhere, yes? If so, I can tell you now that I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Then you probably have something else that is wrong. Are you able to play these files by clicking on the element's controls?

Comment: @Kaiido Yes I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a browser glitch. I made a new HTML file with another audio element and it worked so I went to the beginning and worked my way to every page with audio and they all worked. Thanks for trying everyone!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).