# Autoplay Audio in Loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

i am looking for autoplay an audio in loop without getting blocked by browser.

Code :

```
<audio id="audio1" src="assest/sound/1.mp3" autoplay="" />
      <script>
         a = document.getElementById('audio1');
         
         a.onended = function(){setTimeout("a.play()", 1000)}
      </script>
```

My current code working on firefox but in default it is blocked, i have to allow autoplay manually so it can play the audio and in other side in chrome the audio is not even playing.

Edited :

Iframe code :

```
<iframe src="assest/sound/1.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="iframeAudio">
</iframe>
```

I have even tried iframe auto play code but it still not working with chrome. iframe code automatically trigger auto download of audio file.

Any solution for this?

Comment: you can see here ? [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Comment: All those solution, i have already tried and none of them working even iframe one.

Comment: @NigelRen your comment is out of topic. i am still looking for answer for autoplay. ones i find answer i will make as answered.

Answer (score 1):

WITH HTML

```
<audio controls autoplay loop hidden>
    <source src="assest/sound/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Your code is not working with chrome :(

Comment: @shanmugapradeep , What version of chrome are you using ?, I tested it and it worked,
i am using chrome **Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Comment: @JulioEnsutias `Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)` - same what you mentioned but it still not work for me :(

Comment: nothing changes here i tried too.... sigh :(

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this document to know what is the problem that you're facing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide.

As described in the document:

> As a general rule, you can assume that media will be allowed to autoplay only if at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The audio is muted or its volume is set to 0
> - The user has interacted with the site (by clicking, tapping, pressing keys, etc.)
> - If the site has been allowlisted; this may happen either automatically if the browser determines that the user engages with media frequently, or manually through preferences or other user interface features
> - If the autoplay feature policy is used to grant autoplay support to an  and its document.

I think a reasonable way is to let users interact with your site first. Eg:

- Show an in-page popup and the user clicks to close it;
- Ask users whether they want to listen to music or not;
- ...

After they interacted with your site, you can run the script to play the audio without browser blocking.