# Making an Azan (alarm clock) to open an mp3 file when specific time in api and the device matches

Tags: javascript

I am building an Azan clock with Javascript with the following code, but the code does not launch the mp3 file when the time from the API and my PC match.

I am already converting the system time to string time to match with the API but it is kind of ignored by the console.

Screenshot of time format in console

[image: both the system and API time matches]

My code is below

```
// Enable JQuery
var script = document.createElement("script");

script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js";

document.head.appendChild(script);

// Call and Parse the API
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open(
  "GET",
  "https://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=AbuDhabi&country=uae&method=8",
  false
); // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);
if (request.status === 200) {
  var azan = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
}

// Convert system time format

var convertFormat = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
  hour: "numeric",
  hour12: false,
  minute: "numeric",
});

// Play the mp3 file if it is time
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
  playazan();
  console.log("Checking Prayer Time");
}, 5000);

function playazan() {
  if (azan.data.timings.Asr === convertFormat) {
    new Audio('https://www.islamcan.com/audio/adhan/azan20.mp3').play()
    console.log("Its time for Dhuhrr");
  } else {
    console.log("Still time remains");
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490453/5953610