# I want to play audio and video simultaneously, as autoplay can't be used without muted attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Here I tried to play audio and video simultaneously, but the page goes blank when I try to run it. Is there a way I can fix this?
This is the code

```
import React from 'react'
import './home.css'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import video1 from './Ankit.mp4';
import Newhome from './Newhome';
import audio from './sound.mp3';
export default function Home() {
    
    const [showVideo, setShowVideo] = useState(true);
    useEffect(
        () => {
            let timer1 = setTimeout(() => setShowVideo(false), 3500);
            return () => {
                // <div>Best viewed on mobile for now</div>
            clearTimeout(timer1);
          };
        },
        []
      );
    return (
        <>
            {showVideo ? <video  muted autoPlay loop className='logo_video2' >
                <source src={video1} type="video/mp4" />
                  <audio controls>
                <source src={audio} type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>
            </video> : <Newhome/>}
        </>
    )
}
```

`showVideo` is used to play a logo and 3.5 seconds after all content will be displayed.

Comment: add sample in codesandbox is better for debugging

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-allen-xy6cdi?file=/src/COMPONENTS/Home.jsx:777-875

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the prop `Home` to `Audio` component, as you can see the below, and in Audio component you are giving the wrong audio tag you have to change the `Audio` to `audio`.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
export default function Audio({ src }) {
  useEffect(() => {
const eleId = document.getElementById("audioId");
   if (eleId) {
     eleId.src = src;
     eleId.play();
    }
  }, [src]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <audio id="audioId" autplay controls></audio>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Home.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./home.css";
import Audio from "./Audio";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import video1 from "./Ankit.mp4";
import Newhome from "./Newhome";
import audio from "./sound.mp3";
export default function Home() {
  const [showVideo, setShowVideo] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer1 = setTimeout(() => setShowVideo(false), 3500);
    return () => {
      // <div>Best viewed on mobile for now</div>
      clearTimeout(timer1);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {showVideo ? (
        <video muted autoPlay loop className="logo_video2">
          <source src={video1} type="video/mp4" />
          <Audio src={audio}></Audio>
        </video>
      ) : (
        <Newhome />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```