# Flutter: how to autoplay audio at startup on the web?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, audio

I'd like my Flutter game to start its music when the app is loaded into Chrome.
Chrome disables audio autoplay because ads abuse it.  Is there a way around this for a Flutter app?

Or do I have to rely on manually editing the built HTML file to include one of the general autoplay hacks, like in [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome) ?

Comment: I think it’s probably best to embrace the restriction. Have a click / “press key” to start screen that will satisfy the “user interaction“ condition of the auto play policy

Comment: Thanks @fdcpp .  I didn't read carefully in the question I linked to see that all their methods were no longer working anyway.  I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  None of the methods in the linked question work anymore.  Have the user click or press a key to start the game and then you can start audio.