# Why audio is not playing when a HTML page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I would like to play a sound on a load of an HTML page. First I tried this solution:

```
<audio src="static/audio/lang/pchwcafckzdmfcvuneezavatquflye_en.mp4" id="my_audio" loop="loop" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
    }
</script>
```

It did not work. Then I have tried this one:

```
<audio src="static/audio/lang/pchwcafckzdmfcvuneezavatquflye_en.mp4" id="my_audio" loop="loop" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sample = document.getElementById("my_audio");
sample.play();
</script>
```

This does not work as well. In have tried to load the page in Chrome as well as Firefox. In both browsers if does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Dev Console (F12 in Chrome)?

Comment: Check the console as @DorinBotan says and I believe you will see an error such as: "NotAllowedError: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Autoplay with sound is disabled and policies updated in Chrome and Firefox

Check these articles:

- [Autoplay policy in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)
- [Audio Autoplay in Chrome](https://enablenowexpert.com/?p=908#:%7E:text=The%20actual%20Chrome%20policy%20is,previously%20played%20video%20with%20sound.)
- [Chrome autoplay policy changes](https://help.mypurecloud.com/articles/chrome-autoplay-policy-changes/)
- [Autoplay guide for media and Web Audio APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)