# Why I can't play audio automatically using html?

Tags: html, web, audio, browser, html5-audio

I'm trying to make web page in which there will be music playing in background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Website </title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to my website</h2>
    <audio src="sound.mp3" controls autoplay>
        <p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.     </p>
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see audio player, so web page can find mp3 file for sure.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GERM.png)

I tried many different approaches (audio tag, embed tag, iframe, some js scripts) but I can only make audio player and I have to turn on music manually, and I can't find way to start playing music, when i enter web page. My browser is opera gx, but i tried also do this in edge with same results. Do you have any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Playing music or video automatically without user input is considered abhorrent and intrusive. From Google: "From the user's perspective, a web page or app that spontaneously starts making noise without warning can be jarring, inconvenient, or off-putting. Because of that, browsers generally only allow autoplay to occur successfully under specific circumstances."

Comment: It sounds like you have control over the browser (My browser is opera gx...), in which case this works: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#developer_switches

Answer (score 0):

#### Many browsers block web pages from auto-playing audio

This is because many people (including me!) are annoyed when web pages play sounds without their permission, since they may be in a quiet area, where it is disruptive to others.

#### Chrome is a good example

Google explained this in this blog post:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

More information on the Chromium project website:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/audio-video/autoplay

#### Try different browsers

You might find a browser that is less thoughtful. This might be acceptable to you, if it is just for your own use, or your end-users are happy to have auto-playing sound and therefore to use a particular browser for your page.

Answer (score -1):

This is because Chromium-based browsers disallow autoplay

There are plenty of possible approaches discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome), or you can simply Google for `"autoplay audio in chromium browsers"` to find more.