# Sound not playing; Javascript/html

Tags: javascript

I want to play a sound on my website, but it doesn't work.
I've already tried everything:

```html
<audio id="ringtone" src="Sound2.mp3"></audio>
```

```js
RingSound = document.getElementById("ringtone");
RingSound.play();
```

I also tried another method:

```
var Sound = new Audio('Sound2.mp3')
Sound.play();
```

Everything didn't work out, but the sound of the computer works. I've tried almost everything, moved the file, done audio test.
I hope someone can help me

Comment: The code you've got should work, but note that sound can only be played if the user has 'interacted' with the page - eg. by clicking a button to initiate the sound. You cannot play annoying sounds immediately when the page loads. If you open the console in devtools you'll see a message regarding suppressed sounds if this is the case.

Comment: Any useful error messages in the browser's console?

Comment: Soft duplicate: [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome). Other commenters have already addressed that this is largely not possible without the media being triggered as part of a user interaction event.